# How to set the default parameter value of a function for a user-defined table type?

Tags: sql-server

I have a user-defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EntityKeysTable] AS TABLE
                  (
                    [EntityKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED( [EntityKey] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
                  )
```

And a function that uses it...  But that function is being used by different processes in our system and I don't want to go in and have to deal with the new parameter everywhere, so I rather just make it optional by having a default value in it...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnMyFunctionNameHere]
    (@siteId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
     @entityKeys AS EntityKeysTable READONLY, 
     @partialDeploy AS BIT = false) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
   RETURN (
      WITH Overrides AS (
        SELECT * ....
```

I did it for the `@partialDeploy` but unsure about how to do the same for the `@entityKeys`.

Comment: BTW I have tried setting `@entityKeys` to `null`.  `@entityKeys as EntityKeysTable = null READONLY` gives me "Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with EntityKeysTable" and `@entityKeys as EntityKeysTable READONLY = null` gives me "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my prior misleading information.

Table valued functions cannot be null. But you can define them with no records in it. So, you would check for `(select count(*) from @entityKeys) = 0` to check if there are entityKeys or not.

```
if (select count(*) from @entityKeys) = 0
   --load @entityKeys as your wish
```

Comment: `@entityKeys AS EntityKeysTable READONLY = null` throws a syntax error "Incorrect syntax near '='." , that was the first thing I tried... and `@entityKeys as EntityKeysTable = null READONLY` throws "Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with EntityKeysTable"

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I also searched for the answer to this question, but found nothing. So I did such:

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.Test
    @table dbo.testType readonly
AS
BEGIN
    declare  @table2 dbo.testType
    if(not exists(select * from @table))
        .... do something like 
             insert into @table2(t1,t2) values ....
     else
        insert into @table2(t1,t2) select t1,t2 from @table

     ... do main code using  @table2
END
```

User defined table types is optional. So you may not pass it to function.